# htaccess Redirection page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is it possible to do a redirect (->) in de .htaccess-file, the following way? :

```
www.website1.com/blog/2020/abc -> www.website2.com/blog/2020/abc
www.website1.com/blog/2021/rst -> www.website2.com/blog/2021/rst
www.website1.com/blog/2022/xyz -> www.website2.com/blog/2022/xyz
```

Here is my sample of how I am doing this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://website2.com/blog/%1 [R=301,NC]
```

Thanks in advance,
Vandna

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you want to redirect all of `website1.com` to `website2.com`? Or just `/blog`? Or even just `/blog/<year>`?

Comment: I have 2 different websites with a blog section.

I'd like to redirect website1's blog pages to website2's blog page.

I have URLs like 

www.website1.com/blog/2020/abc -> www.website2.com/blog/2020/abc

I hope now you are able to understand.

Comment: @anubhava I've added my sample code. Please have a look and let me know what I am missing.

Comment: Yes, It is working now. There was a small mistake.